# Source for parsing C grammar using JavaCC

Tags: grammar, javacc

As an project assignment, I need to parse a plain-C grammar from Java to generate AST output. As a startup, I am using the file c.jj that I have found among grammar files at

http://java.net/projects/javacc/sources/svn/

but I found that it only has syntactic and lexical actions and no real semantics for parsing C source. Is there some other source that incorporate typedef, variables, construct functions, include files?

Answer (score 1):

You could go looking for a complete grammar.  Will you learn much this way?

You could ask your lecturer which would impress them more: implementing some small subset of C grammar by writing your own rules, or by searching google for alternative complete rules?

I trust writing your own rules - and even your own hand-crafted parser - will be more a more useful exercise.  Even if its only parsing expressions.

Comment: You must be a college dropout. just kidding

Comment: well no kidding I did ok at college.  It might be that your tutor wants you to solve this problem using google, but I rather hope they actually want to see you write code to parse something yourself.