# Generate Object Model/AST of C program in Java

Tags: java, c, object, model, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to parse a C source file and get its contents into an AST (abstract syntax tree). It would be very nice if I had my AST stored in Java objects, similar to a XML parsed with DOM. The concepts of Eclipse CDT seem to be what I want, except that it is designed to be a plugin library. Does anybody know whether there are standalone libraries for that, such as DOM for XML?
I've already read other topics at stackoverflow concering ASTs and so on, but I'm not quite sure if ANTLR or JavaCC it the right solution for me.
Thanks in advance!

André

Comment: You might tell more about your real motivations. What exactly do you want to do with the C AST?

Comment: Sounds very similar to my course work in uni, i strongly recommend you to go with ANTLR. Otherwise, go and grab dragon book and start building your own parser, which is not easy task.

Comment: Actually, I have an existing Java application and need to extend it. My task is to implement a feature that checks whether given variables or constants (I have their name and types) are really used within the C source file. For example, if I have a "bool testme" given in my program, my task is to verify whether "testme" is referenced anywhere in the source file. ---- EDIT ---- To keep it simple... say I merely have a program that takes an variable name as argument and outputs whether that variable is actually used within a given source file.

Comment: You might want use JavaCC - see details in
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296029/source-for-parsing-c-grammar-using-javacc

Comment: "See whether <var> is referenced anywhere in the source file".  So, you need to parse the C code, do all the necessary preprocessing (what if it is referenced in a macro or an deeply nested include?), determine all identifiers of the same name and verify that the you want is used in the scope in which it is defined.  You might be able to do this with just a pure AST, but surely this isn't a specific goal of your organization? (Most compilers will tell you this anyway).  If you want to any further, you'll actually need to collect type informatoin (in fact most C parsers need this to work)...

Comment: ... you'll probably want a full symbol table, some understanding of control and data flow, ... in short, you want lots more than a parser.  People keep making the mistake of believing that if they have a parser, somehow Nirvana is just a step away.   It isn't so. Check out my essay on Life After Parsing:  http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/LifeAfterParsing.html  Bottom line: you really don't want to build your own parser; go find one with all the extra facilities.  If you insist on staying in Java, you'd be far better off finding how to use CDT than building your own.

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps consider customizing an existing compiler. For example, GCC admit plugins, and also [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extensions. MELT is a high-level domain specific language to designed to easily extend GCC, and is able to work on GCC internal representations (Gimple, Tree).

I would strongly suggest you to avoid parsing C yourself (e.g. by diving into ANTLR ...). This is a bigger task than what you imagine.

An advantage of working inside some existing compiler framework (like GCC or Clang/LLVM) is that you benefit at once of all the compiler's machinery. Also, you can (for compilers accepting several source languages, like GCC) also handle other languages than C (e.g. C++, Go, Ada, Fortran, Objective C for GCC). And a compiler compute a lot of things (Use/Def chains, cross-references, SSA form) that may be useful to you. At last, you can work on some suitable predigested internal representation, which may be more useful to you than the plain C abstract syntax tree. (For instance, you might want to work on Gimple after function inlining).

Last but not least, by extending an existing compiler you can improve its behavior, e.g. give better warnings, or even improve the emitted code.

<sup>But I know no C compiler written in Java!</sup>

Answer (score -1):

There are several Parser Generators for Java available, see:

http://java-source.net/open-source/parser-generators

You might want to look into the types of parsers - they can be LL(K), LALR and the like. The differences are outlined in the compiler theory that was developed in the 1960s and 70s. You might want to read something like Aho/Sethi/Ullmann - Compilers Principles, Techniques and Tools for this theory.

Once you have selected your parser technology you can select your parser - generator tool.
ANTLR (LALR) and JavaCC LL(k) are two which I am personally familiar with and can recommend. On the JavaCC webpage you'll find a grammar example for C which you can start with.

LL(k) grammars are a bit harder to handle since you need conflict handling - but if the grammar is finished and works you should be fine with that approach.

Personally I'd go with JavaCC for your problem.

See  [Source for parsing C grammar using JavaCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296029/source-for-parsing-c-grammar-using-javacc)